# Nest If Getting no output

Tags: java

When compiled and run, i get no output what so ever. Trying to get the output recommended when the cost is less than 100 and has a rating of 4. if else print save your money

```
System.out.print("Enter cost: ");
double cost = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter a Star value between 1-4");
int rating = input.nextInt();

if (cost < 100){
    if (rating == 4 )
        System.out.println("Recommended");
}
else
    System.out.println("Save your money");
```

Comment: What values do you enter?

Comment: If cost is less than 100 and rating is not equal to 4, you won't get output.

Comment: cost and rating, Trying to get the output recommended when the cost is less than 100 and has a rating of 4. if else print save your money

Comment: That's how it currently works, yes.

Comment: when i run i cant get it to print out "save your money"

Comment: Then you are not running it with `cost <100` and `rating == 4`.

Comment: i figured it out by moving the end brace to after (rating == 4)

Comment: Even if you are only having 1 line of code after an if statement, you should use `{ }`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it to print 'recommended' when rating is 4 and cost is < 100 then you could do this:

```
if (cost < 100 && rating == 4)
    System.out.println("Recommended");
else
    System.out.println("Save your money");
```

Answer (score 0):

its something like no need to give two if loops at all. u can have && operator for the making that in once if loop.

```
if(cost < 100 && rating == 4)
```

that is the desired solution and what is the meaning of giving if two time when there no need of that.

still u need same ans from your method use this.

```
if (cost<100) {
            if (rating==4) {
                System.out.println("Recomanded");
            }   


        }else {
            System.out.println("Save your money");
        }
```

Comment: @user3250337 your welcome i will be happy if that can help u use new ans for your trick that i have updated.